# android how to moving many image on my destination point

Tags: android

how to implement my idea with android source code

i have many image, i want to move image one by one, if image move on destination point, then other image  moving on behind image previous.

ilustration

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

image1,image2,image3                           x (point destination move)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

if image3 move

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
image1,image2                           image3 x

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

if image2 move then image3 follow move image2

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
image1                           image2,image3 x

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
```

and so on

how to implementation to source code android

i am newbie

thanks

Answer (score 1):

For moving objects, in android we have a concept called TranslateAnimation.
Here is the sample snippet for moving  my object from left to right:

```
ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Animation");

moveLefttoRight = new TranslateAnimation(0, 200, 0, 0);
moveLefttoRight.setDuration(1000);
moveLefttoRight.setFillAfter(true);

button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
button.setText("PressMe");
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        tv.startAnimation(moveLefttoRight);
    }

});

ll.addView(tv);
ll.addView(button);
setContentView(ll);
```

Then, you can apply the same trick to your three images..

Hope this will helps you..

Comment: Ii it helpful to your question, make it as correct answer or vote up..This will help to the people, who are face the same issue..

Comment: hmm,,,,,your answer is litle helpfull, your answer is using button, i want to using slide using drag finger and using surfaceview,,,,
you can help me again?

i want to create simple application like abacus :)